# Loader для старых браузеров

Tags: javascript, html, loader

Леплю сайт. Дошло время для создания Loader'а. Когда я его слепил с одного CSS (div и css-анимация), то обнаружил, что в ie (Windows XP) он не работает.

По какой технике сделать Loader, чтобы работал в IE 7,8,9 без проблем?

P.S. Я додумался пока что только до GIF

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.double-bounce1, .double-bounce2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.6;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  
  -webkit-animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation: sk-bounce 2.0s infinite ease-in-out;
}

.double-bounce2 {
  -webkit-animation-delay: -1.0s;
  animation-delay: -1.0s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes sk-bounce {
  0%, 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.0) }
  50% { -webkit-transform: scale(1.0) }
}

@keyframes sk-bounce {
  0%, 100% { 
    transform: scale(0.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
  } 50% { 
    transform: scale(1.0);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinner">
  <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
  <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Скиньте исходник.  я постараюсь что-то сделать

Comment: Используйте http://jqueryui.com/resources/download/jquery-ui-1.12.1.zip  и http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/ на этой страничке все показано. и не забудьте подключить http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js

Comment: А кому-то нужен IE? Один вопрос - зачем? :)

Comment: @Duoxx, выложил

Comment: В данном случае реально лучше использовать гифки

Comment: @Yuri если так нужно это вам то второй вариант может быть анимация на `js`, но как я сейчас думаю, сделать это будет не просто. если конечно `GIF` не устраивает, кроме этих двух нету других технологий `старых времен`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan, я тоже подумываю. Но вот будут ли старые браузера поддерживать к примеру какие-то плагины для анимаций? Это вопрос

Comment: @Yuri мне кажется если это не будут технологии последних 2-3 лет то будет.

Comment: @Yuri, наверное стоит поменять метку `старые-браузера` на `internet-explorer`. Она у вас еще и с ошибкой.

Comment: @Visman, я же не только про ie пишу. Есть и Chrome старый, и Опера...

Comment: @Yuri, опера 12 разве проблемы имеет с анимацией? `Chrome старый` такого понятия не существует ;)

Comment: @Yuri Вот я дал один пример ответа, посмотрите подойдет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример вашего `loader`-а на `jQuery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var item1 = $('.double-bounce1');
  var item2 = $('.double-bounce2');

  function animate_func() {
    var item1_w_h = item1.width() - 1;
    if (item1_w_h > 1) {
      var item2_w_h = 41 - item1_w_h;
      item1.css({
        'left': item2_w_h / 2,
        'top': item2_w_h / 2,
        'width': item1_w_h,
        height: item1_w_h
      });
      item2.css({
        'left': item1_w_h / 2,
        'top': item1_w_h / 2,
        'width': item2_w_h,
        height: item2_w_h
      });
    } else {
      var tmp = item1;
      item1 = item2;
      item2 = tmp;
    }
  }
  slider_timer = setInterval(animate_func, 25);
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #2c3e50;
}

.spinner {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.double-bounce1,
.double-bounce2 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.double-bounce2 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="spinner">
  <div class="double-bounce1"></div>
  <div class="double-bounce2"></div>
</div>
```

Он работает со всеми библиотеками `jQuery`. Тестировал на `IE8` и нормально заработало, на `IE7` не работает поскольку в нем даже нет поддержки стиля `border-radius`.
Логика простая с помощью функции `setInterval` меняем высоту и ширину блоков, и еще ее центр, поскольку стили `left` и `top` считываются с левого верхнего края блока. И если не рассчитать их то центры блоков не будут совпадать кода их размеры разные.

Comment: @Yuri А что там было менять?